# How can I know if a given file has finished uploading from another location?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp, upload

Let's say we have **machine 1** and **machine 2**.
**Machine 2**, which is linux based, is receiving a file (let's say **cat.jpg** sent via SCP from **machine 1** (doesn't really matter which operating system..).

How can I know in **machine 2**, that the file has finished uploading from **machine 1** ?
Please note that by "knowing" I mean by running a command (via a cron that runs every minute), and not by an event driven way ("make the scp issue a command when it is finished uploading").

Another limitation I have is that I can't change anything in **machine 1** or in the way it SCP files.

If it really matters:

- the files being transferred are video file, MP4 extension.
- **machine 2** is ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Check if the receiving process still exists.

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to use the [lsof](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/) command to check if the file is open in another program.

```
lsof | grep filename
```

if you get a result the file is open in another process and probably still uploading. If the result is blank the file is finished uploading or possibly the transfer failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a cleverer way of doing it, but in these situations I just use `ls` to show the file size and then wait for it to stop changing for a reasonable period of time (10-20 secs) -eg:

```
watch ls -l *.mp4
```

Comment: This might be unsafe. E.g. if you _replace_ the existing file with the same or larger size

Answer (score 1):

```
fuser -mv / 2>&1 | grep F
```

That will list all users, pid and files open and in writing in a given mount-point.

Answer (score 0):

as root:

```
fuser filename
```

If something is printed out, then the file is currently used by some process.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
while [ true ]; do
    SAMPLE1=`ls -l --full-time $FILE`
    sleep 5
    SAMPLE2=`ls -l --full-time $FILE`
    if [ "$SAMPLE1" == "$SAMPLE2" ]; then
      echo done!
      break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to rather safely assume that the `scp` command is over, is to list the files that have been modified more than 30s ago:

```
find /tmp/*mp4 -mmin +0.5
```

Now, you could decrease/increase the `mtime` value to make the file processing quicker/safer.